# Erro no login PHP, o cadastro ta funcionando normal, só que o login não conecta de acordo com os cadastros no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

ESTA DANDO ESSE ERRO QUANDO VAI ENTRAR :

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hosste\Login_v1\userauthentication.php on line 28
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hosste\Login_v1\userauthentication.php on line 28

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";    
$user = "root";    
$pass = "";    
$db = "tomorrow";    
$conexao =mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());    
mysqli_select_db($conexao, $db) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<html>    
<head>    
    <title>Autenticando usuário</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        function loginsuccessfully() {    
            setTimeout("window.location='painel.php'",  5000);    
        }
        function loginfailed(){    
            setTimeout("window.location='login.php'",  5000);    
        }    
    </script>    
</head>    
<body>
    
    <?php
    
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $senha=$_POST['senha'];
    $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' and senha = '$senha'") or die(mysqli_error());
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if($row > 0){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
        $_SESSION['senha']=$_POST['senha'];
        echo "<center>Você foi autenticado com sucesso!</center>";
        echo "<script>loginsuccessfully()</script";
    } else {
        echo "<center>Nome de usuario ou senha invalido!</center>";    
        echo "<script>loginfailed()</script>";
    }
    
    ?>    
</body>    
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que `var_dump($_POST)` imprime, assim que você envia o form?

Comment: men nao entendi, eu vi em um tutorial isso ai

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa passar o recurso link retornado pelo `mysqli_connect()`, no seu caso você precisa passar a variável `$conexao` como parâmetro pro  `mysqli_query()`. O mesmo recurso deve ser passado para o `mysqli_error()`

Deve ficar assim:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' and senha = '$senha'") or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
```

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php)